# Distinguishing The actions of updating and creation in django M2M signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I wish to do the following. When a new project is created , i want to notify everybody that was assigned to the project that there's a new project available.

Here is my simplified project model:

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):
    sales_project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    userProfile = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords(excluded_fields=['version', 'project_status'])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sales_project_name
```

When a project is being created, i will send out the following signal :

```
def CreateProjectNotification(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == "post_add" and kwargs["model"] == UserProfile:

        for person in kwargs['instance'].userProfile.all():

            #some check here to prevent me from creating a notification for the creator or the project
            Notifications.objects.create(
                target= person.user,
                extra = 'Sales Project',
                object_url = '/project/detail/' + str(kwargs['instance'].pk) + '/',
                title = 'New Sales Project created')
```

The reason why im using the m2m_changed.connect instead of post_save is because i wish to access the M2M field , UserProfile to send out the notifications. Since the object would not be added to the through table at the point of creation , i can't use the post_save and instead i have to track the changes from the through table .

problem
With that said , this signal runs as long as the save() function is called and the model which changed was the UserProfile model .

This is problematic as for example , i don't wish to send this same message when a new user was added. Instead i wish to run a separate signal to handle for that.

Is there a way , other than using if else to distinguish between a creation of the object and adding of a related M2M object?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a `Notification` when a new `SalesProject` is created?

Comment: Yup! But the catch is that i wish to access the userprofile model through an M2M field , which is why i have to use the m2m change method

Comment: the 2nd thing i wish to do , is to distinguish between an 'update' and a 'create' that's because the by using m2m_change , the function is run whenever there's a change to the through table , hence i can't differentiate if the action was an 'update' or a 'create'

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using signals as much as possible as they are bad practise as [explained here](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/).

You should override the `save()` function of your `SalesProject` model and handle any logic in there. It is possible to check if a `SalesProject` is created or updated by using [`self._state.adding`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading).

`self._state.adding == True` means the `SalesProject` is created

`self._state.adding == False` means the `SalesProject` is updated

Thus to achieve what you want:

```py
class SalesProject(models.Model):
    sales_project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    userProfile = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords(excluded_fields=['version', 'project_status'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:  # check if object is created and not updated
            # your logic goes here i.e. create/delete (related) objects
        return super(SalesProject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sales_project_name
```

**EDIT**

Lets say you create an `UserProfile` object and want to add it as a relation to a `SalesProject` object by assigning it to its `userProfile` field. To get any values of a newly created `UserProfile` object, it has to be saved to the database first.

An example:

```py
# SalesProject model class

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(someField=someValue)
        self.userProfile.add(user_profile)
    return super(SalesProject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `UserProfile.objects.create()` will create a new `UserProfile` with the values that you assign to the fields and save it to the database.

`self.userProfile.add(user_profile)` adds the newly created and saved `UserProfile` as a relation to the ManyToManyField of the `SalesProject` that was just created.

Comment: It would seem like placing all the code within fhe save method would make my models.py extremely complicated as theres alot of different conditions that i wish to take into account for. (Not shown in here) I believe that that would really make readability suffer , so what i did was to create a seperate signal folder dedicated just for notifications. Is there a way to replicate the self._state.adding within the signals? That being said i will explore putting the logic into the save method in the meantime

Comment: One way to keep your `save()` cleaner is to create functions for the checks and import them in your models. As far as I know it is not possible to replicate the `self._state.adding` in a m2m_changed signal. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666140/prevent-m2m-changed-from-firing-when-creating-an-object) has some workarounds if you insist on using the m2m_changed signal

Comment: hey @Stevy , im having troubles translating the above to work in my case. I think the save() method could work out however , lets say in one particular update , i am adding a new userProfile my through table,  how would i go about obtaining this value as at the point of saving it doesnt appear yet

Comment: @neowenshun, I added an edit to my answer. Let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: alright , thanks . The way my application is set up , the userProfile is merely an assignment to the Project. However , it would seem that in order to that , i would need to pass in the form data to know which instance or userProfile to add to my relation , do you know a way to do that?

Comment: I am not familair with forms in Django but this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) should be able to help you out